# Create multiple buttons with multiple functions

Tags: html

I have 0 coding knowledge, but hoping you guys can assist with modifying this code I found online to create multiple buttons to execute different bat files. I would save it as an hta file so it can be run in a win shell environment. Thank you!!!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Batch Files</title>
    <SCRIPT type="text/jscript">
        window.moveTo(500,500);
        window.resizeTo(730,100);
    </SCRIPT>
        <HTA:APPLICATION ID="oMyApp" 
        APPLICATIONNAME="Application Executer" 
        SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
        SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
        SYSMENU="yes"
        SCROLL="no"
        WINDOWSTATE="normal">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function button1() {
        RunExe
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("c:/hub/dd.bat", 1, false);
        }
        function button2() {
        RunExe
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("c:/hub/dd2.bat", 1, false);
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    SELECT THE BATCH FILE:
    <input id="b1" type="button" value="Batch 1" onclick="button1();"/>
    <input id="b2" type="button" value="Batch 2" onclick="button2();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably you should start by gaining some coding knowledge, check out a few tutorials because Stack Overflow is not a "write my code for me" sort of website.

Comment: I would suggest you never run "this code I found online", unless you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You could give every button an unique id.

```
<input id="write_your_id_here" style="width: 170px; height:23px; color: white; background-color:    #203040; 
 font-family:Book Antiqua;" type="button" Value="Start Chrome" 
 onClick=RunExe()
```

"onClick" is for telling the button what to do when clicked.

Comment: <input id="write_your_id_here" style="width: 170px; height:23px; color: white;   
      background-color:    #203040; font-family:Book Antiqua;" type="button" Value="Start Chrome" 
    onClick=RunExe()

Thank you for the reply. How can I then associate the second button with the diff ID to a new function?

Comment: You should copy the code for every button and edit the id.

Comment: The onClick=RunExe() points to: 
    function RunExe(){
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var path = '"C:/HUB/dd.bat"';
    shell.run(path,1,false);

If I create a second button it would still point to the same function. I am not sure how to rewrite it so that there are unique functions this way the different buttons can point to the different functions. 
Thank you!

Comment: If you want unique functions, you have to write them first and then edit the function name on the buttons onClick=functionname()

Comment: function button1(){ RunExe
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var path = '"C:/HUB/dd.bat"';
    shell.run(path,1,false);

onClick=button1()
---no go..

Comment: Not sure how to write it so that the function includes the function name followed by RunExe. That's where it crashes.

Comment: You can just copy the function and chance the name "Runexe()" to "Runexe2()". I recommend learning basic coding by some tutorials like others have adviced.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the code, above and worked, but now stopped working and am now getting an error that "RunExe" is unidentified.

Comment: write function runexe() instead of function button1()